# want to loop through dataframe and convert time into readable R format

Tags: r, loops, time, dataframe, apply

I want to turn the column x$Timestamp into time R can read using as.POSIXct and the new readable time in x$Timestamp. I am looking to use apply or a for loop. Any ideas?

code:

```
x;
    Timestamp Barcode
1   2014-01-11 2012576
2   2014-01-11 2012458
3   2014-01-11 2012463
4   2014-01-11 2012421
5   2014-01-11 2012457
6   2014-01-11 2012416
7   2014-01-11 2012468
8   2014-01-11 2012462
9   2014-01-11 2012452
10  2014-01-11 2012511
11  2014-01-11 2012437
12  2014-01-11 2012406
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a for loop, this is R!  You can simply do this:

```
x$pTimestamp <- as.POSIXct(x$Timestamp)
```

Comment: @ weitzner, I should have been more clear, I can do the above, I want to do that but also keep the barcode associate with the time stamp. Sorry I am new, please forgive. cheers chad

Comment: The above line will just add a third column to your data.frame.  The converted data will be in the same order as the initial column, so the barcodes will still be in sync with the new column.

Comment: @ could I just do this x[,1] <- as.POSIXct(x[,1]), and change class since date is already in correct form, but wrong class?

Comment: Yes.  You could even use the column title, which is considered more readable and stylish, like so:`x$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(x$Timestamp)`

Comment: @ thanks alot weitzner, you were a big help. Thanks for the quick lesson. cheers